# webkit returns blank screen even after I set the app transport security

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var web: WKWebView?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!)
        web?.load(request)
    }
}
```